# Completing squares with three variables.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I want to complete the squares for this polynomial 
$2x^2+2y^2-z^2+2xy+3xz-4yz$

Is there any kind of easy and non-confusing way to solve it?
I’ve done this up until now:

$$2x^2+2y^2-z^2+2xy+3xz-4yz$$
$$2x^2+2xy+3xz-4yz+2y^2-z^2$$
$$2(x^2+xy+\frac{3}{2}xz)-4yz+2y^2-z^2$$
$$2(x^2+x(y+\frac{3}{2}z))-4yz+2y^2-z^2$$
$$2(x^2+x(y+\frac{3}{2}z))+(\frac{1}{2}(y+\frac{3}{2}z))^2-(\frac{1}{2}(y+\frac{3}{2}z))^2-4yz+2y^2-z^2$$

Then things get kinda messy from here and I get totally lost from then on, could anyone help me out factoring this? And telling me if there is an eaay and non-confusing way to solve it?

Comment: There's Gauß' method  for writing a quadratic form as a sum of squares, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @Bernard Historical note: Gauss, or ‘Gauß’ as it is spelled in modern German, actually wrote his name “Gau s” with a long ess. Handwritten, it looks more like “Gau s.”

Comment: @Bernard I don’t know why my copy-pasting is malfunctioning… look up [“long ess”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) if you’re curious

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor:  I didn't know how his name was written at the time. Well, the `ß` is just the ligature of a long  `ſ` with a short `s`.

Answer (score 0):

Original is $$2x^2+2y^2-z^2-4yz+3zx+2xy$$

Fine until
$$2(x^2+xy+\frac{3}{2}xz)-4yz+2y^2-z^2$$
at which point you want to stop, and calculate
$$  \left(x + \frac{y}{2} + \frac{3z}{4}  \right)^2 = x^2 + \frac{y^2}{4} + \frac{9 z^2}{16} + \frac{3yz}{4}  + \frac{3zx}{2} + xy, $$ so
$$ 2 \left(x + \frac{y}{2} + \frac{3z}{4}  \right)^2 =  2x^2 + \frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{9 z^2}{8} + \frac{3yz}{2}  + 3zx + 2xy \; \; .$$
 $$2x^2+2y^2-z^2-4yz+3zx+2xy - 2 \left(x + \frac{y}{2} + \frac{3z}{4}  \right)^2 = \frac{3y^2}{2} - \frac{17 z^2}{8} - \frac{11yz}{2}$$

=======================================================================

Here is a way to do it with matrices, the first of which is the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives of the function:

The final matrix equation, $Q^T DQ = H$ gives
$$2x^2+2y^2-z^2-4yz+3zx+2xy = 2 \left(x + \frac{y}{2} + \frac{3z}{4}  \right)^2 + \frac{3}{2} \left(y - \frac{11z}{6}  \right)^2 - \frac{43}{6} z^2 \; \; . $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 4 &  - 4 \\ 
3 &  - 4 &  - 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 3 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 2 }  \\ 
3 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 2 }  &  - 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 3 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 17 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 43 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 11 }{ 6 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 4 &  - 4 \\ 
3 &  - 4 &  - 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 11 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 43 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 6 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 43 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 11 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 4 &  - 4 \\ 
3 &  - 4 &  - 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you mean writing polynomial as the sum of squares, here is one solution:

$p=2x^2+2y^2-z^2+2xy+3xz-4yz$

polynomial p can be written as following forms:

$p=(x+y)^2+(x+z)^2+(y-2z)^2-5z^2+xz$

$p=(x+y)^2 +(x+2z)^2+(y-2z)^2-5z^2 -xz$

Summing these relations and dividing the result by 2 we get:

$p= (x+y)^2 +\frac{1}{2}(x+z)^2+\frac{1}{2}(x+2z)^2 +(y-2z)^2 -(5^{1/2}z)^2$

Answer (score 0):

We can do it simply using $(a \pm b )^2 = a^2 \pm 2ab + b^2$

$$2x^2 + 2y^2 -z^2 + 2xy +3xz - 4yz $$

$$ x^2 + y^2 + 2xy + x^2 +2(x)(\frac{3}{2}z)+(\frac{3}{2}z)^2 -(\frac{3}{2}z)^2+y^2 -2(y)(2z)+(2z)^2 -(2z)^2-z^2$$

$$(x+y)^2 +(x+\frac{3}{2}z)^2 +(y-2z)^2 - (\frac{\sqrt{29}}{2}z)^2 $$